# Firebase - Showing duplicate tableview rows in all tableviews when child is changed/deleted

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I have two issues, both which cause duplicated rows in all of my tableviews in my app:

1. In my tableview, when i swipe to delete an existing value (or row), it all works fine, and my tableview gets refreshed and the row is no longer there. But when a new message appears (or is added under messages in Firebase), every single cell in the messages tableview gets duplicated.
2. Also when the currentuser changes their profile picture , everything works fine, except when i go into the messages tableview , the messages is duplicated?

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    table.refreshControl = refresher

    DataManager.shared.firstVC = self

    self.table.delegate = self
    self.table.dataSource = self
    let postCell = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.table.register(postCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    let answerCell = UINib(nibName: "HasAnsweredYourQuestionTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.table.register(answerCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "hasAnsweredCell")




    self.questions.removeAll()

    Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
        .observe(.childAdded) { (snap) in


            if snap.exists() {


            let obj = snap.value as! [String:Any]
            print(obj)
            let Anonymous = obj["Anonymous"] as! String
            print(Anonymous)
            let questionID = snap.key
            let mess = obj["Message"] as! String
            let timestamp = obj["timestamp"] as! Double
            let from = obj["From"] as! [String:Any]
            let username = from["username"] as? String ?? ""
            let photoURL = from["photoURL"] as? String ?? ""
            let fromID = from["uid"] as? String ?? ""

                Database.database().reference().child("profile").child(fromID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    let thekey = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]
                    let verifiedAsker = thekey?["isVerified"] as! String



                    self.questions.append(Question(questionID: questionID, isAnonymous: Anonymous, message: mess, timestamp: timestamp, fromID: fromID, fromPhoto: photoURL, fromUsername: username, fromVerified: verifiedAsker))
            self.questions.sort(by: {$0.createdAt > $1.createdAt})
            self.table.reloadData()

            })
            }
                else {
                self.table.reloadData()
                }



    }




    Database.database().reference().child("MessageIsAnswered").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).observe(.childAdded) { (snap) in
        let object = snap.key

        Database.database().reference().child("posts").child("\(object)").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
            let theAnsweredQuestion = value["Answer"] as? String ?? ""
            let IdOfAnswerer = value["ToID"] as? String ?? ""
            //let photo_url = value?["photoURL"] as? String ?? ""
            let timeStampo = value["timestamp"] as! Double
            Database.database().reference().child("profile").child(IdOfAnswerer).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in



                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let photo_url = value?["photoURL"] as? String ?? ""
                let usernameOfAnswerer = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""


                self.answers.append(hasAnswered(answererID: IdOfAnswerer, answeredQuestion: theAnsweredQuestion,answererPhoto : photo_url, answererUsername: usernameOfAnswerer, timestampOfAnswer: timeStampo))



    }
}

@IBAction func navigationRightButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    shareView.isHidden = false
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var returnValue = 0
    switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:
        return self.questions.count
        break
    case 1:
        return self.answers.count
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    return returnValue

}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let answeredCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hasAnsweredCell", for: indexPath) as! HasAnsweredYourQuestionTableViewCell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell


    switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
    case 0:



        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        cell.postTextLabel.text = questions[indexPath.row].message
        cell.subtitleLabel.text = questions[indexPath.row].createdAt.calenderTimeSinceNow()

        if self.questions[indexPath.row].fromVerified == "true"{
            cell.isVerifiedImage.image = UIImage(named: "kadabraVerifiedAccount")
        }
        else {
            cell.isVerifiedImage.image = nil

        }

        if self.questions[indexPath.row].isAnonymous != "true"{

            cell.usernameLabel.text = self.questions[indexPath.row].fromUsername
            cell.profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:self.questions[indexPath.row].fromPhoto), placeholderImage: nil, options: .progressiveDownload, completed: nil)


        }
        else {

            cell.usernameLabel.text = ""
            cell.profileImageView.image = nil
            cell.isVerifiedImage.image = nil
        }

        break
    case 1:

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:self.answers[indexPath.row].answererPhoto), placeholderImage: nil, options: .progressiveDownload, completed: nil)
        cell.postTextLabel.text = "\(answers[indexPath.row].answererUsername) has answered your question"
        cell.subtitleLabel.text = moment(self.answers[indexPath.row].timestampOfAnswer) .fromNow()
    cell.usernameLabel.text = ""
    cell.isVerifiedImage.image = nil



        break
    default:
        break
    }

    return cell
    return answeredCell






}


@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {


    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, nil) in




        Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(self.currentUserID!).child(self.questions[indexPath.row].questionID).setValue([])



        self.questions.removeAll()

        Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
            .observe(.childAdded) { (snap) in

                if snap.exists() {



                    let obj = snap.value as! [String:Any]
                    print(obj)
                    let Anonymous = obj["Anonymous"] as! String
                    print(Anonymous)
                    let questionID = snap.key
                    let mess = obj["Message"] as! String
                    let timestamp = obj["timestamp"] as! Double
                    let from = obj["From"] as! [String:Any]
                    let username = from["username"] as? String ?? ""
                    let photoURL = from["photoURL"] as? String ?? ""
                    let fromID = from["uid"] as? String ?? ""

                    Database.database().reference().child("profile").child(fromID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        let thekey = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]
                        let verifiedAsker = thekey?["isVerified"] as! String



                        self.questions.append(Question(questionID: questionID, isAnonymous: Anonymous, message: mess, timestamp: timestamp, fromID: fromID, fromPhoto: photoURL, fromUsername: username, fromVerified: verifiedAsker))
                        self.questions.sort(by: {$0.createdAt > $1.createdAt})
                        self.table.reloadData()
                    })
                }
                else {
                    self.table.reloadData()

                }

        }





        }

    let report = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Report") { (action, view, nil) in

        let areUSureAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you want to report?", message: "This will block this user from sending you anymore questions, and also report the question to the Kadabra team.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)



        areUSureAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

            Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(self.currentUserID!).child(self.questions[indexPath.row].questionID).setValue([])

            self.questions.removeAll()

            Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
                .observe(.childAdded) { (snap) in

                    if snap.exists() {



                        let obj = snap.value as! [String:Any]
                        print(obj)
                        let Anonymous = obj["Anonymous"] as! String
                        print(Anonymous)
                        let questionID = snap.key
                        let mess = obj["Message"] as! String
                        let timestamp = obj["timestamp"] as! Double
                        let from = obj["From"] as! [String:Any]
                        let username = from["username"] as? String ?? ""
                        let photoURL = from["photoURL"] as? String ?? ""
                        let fromID = from["uid"] as? String ?? ""
                        Database.database().reference().child("profile").child(fromID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                            let thekey = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]
                            let verifiedAsker = thekey?["isVerified"] as! String



                            self.questions.append(Question(questionID: questionID, isAnonymous: Anonymous, message: mess, timestamp: timestamp, fromID: fromID, fromPhoto: photoURL, fromUsername: username, fromVerified: verifiedAsker))
                            self.questions.sort(by: {$0.createdAt > $1.createdAt})
                            self.table.reloadData()

                    })
                    }
                    else {
                        self.table.reloadData()
                    }

            }



            let blockedPost = ["timestamp" : [".sv" : "timestamp"]]
            Database.database().reference().child("blocked").child(self.currentUserID!).child(self.questions[indexPath.row].fromID).setValue(blockedPost)



        }))

        areUSureAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            //dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        self.present(areUSureAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)




    }
    report.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.8918681279, blue: 0, alpha: 1)


    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, report])
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "answer", sender: self.questions[indexPath.row])

    case 1:

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "theHasAnswered", sender: self.answers[indexPath.row])


    default:
        break
    }
}
```

It would be great if someone knows why this happens!

Thanks guys.

Comment: Just a note (as I have not looked through all the code), when setting multiple values within a child, it is best to set a dictionary to the master (parent's parent... etc) of that object. Otherwise, if you do `setValue()` on **every** child, this will cause multiple consecutive updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.observe(.childAdded)` method actually returns the entire set of objects under a node when it is invoked for the first time, and then returns newly added objects thereafter.

Also, a Firebase DB observer is not like a normal API call which you *hit* by calling it. You have called the observe method for "messages" multiple times in your code. Instead, call the observer just once. A good way to implement this can be to invoke observer in your `didLoad` just once. It will trigger everytime you perform a change, like deleting an entry.

Also perform the append logic there and reload the tableview in didSet for the questions array. Makes the whole approach a tad bit reactive.

So the root cause for your duplicate entries is that when you add an object, both of your observers in `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` and `didLoad` fire, both appending to the same array.

Also structure your code a bit. It would really help you once you start adding more functionality to your app.

Comment: But what do i add to make it so the cell disappears when delete?  If i just do .setValue[ ] , and then self.table.reloadData (on trailingSwipe) - will that do it ? and just having a observer in viewdidload? Thanks for the answer

Comment: When you call setValue, the `.childChanged` observer will fire automatically after you call setValue. You can then modify your datasource array, and call reload then. A good idea is to add a generic listenForAllEvents observer, which returns the evenType (which could be .childAdded, .childMoved, .childRemoved, .childChanged), and perform changes in the array. Call reload then

Comment: Check out this gist https://gist.github.com/ravitripathi/3efac64eea18e5d701c7472704f93361. Just add this in your didLoad. In it's completion block, use the DataEventType to determine what change occurred, and update your array accordingly

Comment: Okay, but should i add .childAdded, .childMoved, .childRemoved, .childChanged in viewdidload? and then append all of thoose to the same array?

Comment: Yes. Just perform the changes accordingly. So for childAdded append to array, for childRemoved delete it from the array. You can ignore childMoved if you don't care about the order (which I assume you don't because you sort the array). For childChanged you'll have to update the specific row. Again you may ignore this, as  you currently are not manipulating existing data.

Comment: Okay thanks, but in the swipe to delete thing, will i only add tableview.reloaddata()? Could not see what your thoughts on that would be

Comment: Okay see when you do swipe to delete, you want to remove the row from both the tableview as well as the database. Just call your firebase method to remove the value. That's it. Once the call succeeds, the observer function set in didLoad gets a callback, and there your logic will remove the element and reload.

Comment: Okay, but now refering to your original answer, i removed the observer in the trailingSwipeActions and just did tableview.reloadData(), which seems more obvious, but then when i delete an message in the app, the tableview dosent reload (and the old deleted message is still in the tableview?)

Comment: Should i make the observer a function (like you did in github), and call listenForAllChildEvents() in both viewDidLoad and in the trailingSwipe configuration? also i didnt understand what you meant with the childRemoved, how do i configure that with firebase? (sorry but im quite new to firebase)

Comment: 1. The observer will be set in didLoad only.
2. Call the removeValue function to remove data in the firebase db in trailingSwipeActions. Don't reload here.

Comment: As I explained earlier, there are four types of callbacks for firebase db, .childAdded, .childMoved, .childRemoved and .childChanged. .childRemoved is triggered when a object is removed from your db.

Comment: Yes okay great thanks for your time dude, i kind of get your point not. But in childAdded i append the different stuff . But in childRemoved what do i write after observe?

Comment: Also dosent viewDidLoad only load once? when the view is loaded? so when i remove a value, the value will still show until the app is reopened??

Comment: viewDidLoad is called only once. Your observer would be set there. The observer *OBSERVES*. When a value is updated, the completion block is triggered. In childRemoved, iterate through your array and remove the object which corresponds to the snapshot value.  Do read up a bit on the firebase documentation, it would be of great benefit to you.

Comment: Okay i have read a bit about it. But i still dont understand, can you edit your github post to what i should add under childRemoved in my case?